# Why "has_many :line_items, :dependent => destroy" in the cart.rb model file causing failed tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Why

`has_many :line_items, :dependent => destroy`

in the cart.rb model file causing failed tests

I have been working through the "Agile Web Development with Rails" book and am about half way through the depot application (I did skip around a bit).

When I go to run the default test ("the truth") I get failed tests. Trace says

> "/Users/username/Documents/rails_projects/depot/app/models/cart.rb:2:in
>   `destroy': wrong number of arguments
>   (0 for 1) (ArgumentError) from
>   /Users/username/Documents/rails_projects/depot/app/models/cart.rb:2"

If I comment that line out I no longer get the error message and the tests pass. But I don't understand the error message.

What should I be looking at? Is this a valid failure that I need to fix somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> has_many :line_items, :dependent =>
>   :destroy

I think `destroy` is a symbol

Comment: I am new to RoR can you explain further?
Is that line incorrect? Or should it be something else?
I got it from the agile book. I thought the line was saying any dependent items should be destroyed.

Comment: @Maestro1024: You just forgot a `:`, that's all.